# How to work with wilcard subdomains on localhost in a node js application

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am having a application that runs as something.localhost (*.localhost) depending upon the subdomain name action needs to get identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `req.headers.host` to get host identified.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => { 
    if(req.headers.host == 'something.localhost') {
        //your code here
    }
});
```